# bisection search using max() function

Tags: python, bisection

Why did we use max function. Can't we straight away evaluate high to x. That would also achieve our purpose. So, how does the algorithm improves with this max() function?

```
x=25
epsilon=0.01
numGuesses= 0
low =0.0
high = max(1.0,x)
ans = (high+low)/ 2.0
while abs(ans**2 -x)>= epsilon:
    print 'low =', low, 'high =', high, 'ans =', ans
    numGuesses+= 1
    if ans**2 <= x:
        low= ans
    else:
        high= ans
    ans = (high+low)/2.0
print 'numGuesses =', numGuesses
print ans, 'is close to square root of', x
```

Comment: Maybe `x` varies, since this code approximates the square root of `x`.

Comment: :( can't make out can you elaborate @minitech

Comment: This code approximates the square root of `x`. It stands to reason that `x` won’t always be 25. Try it with `high = x` and `x = 0.1`; it never converges.

Comment: This is not really a Python question; it's an algorithms question. If you just want the square root, ask Python directly: `ans = x ** 0.5`, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point of the code is to approximate the square root for any `x` value, not just for 25. We do this by setting a `low` and `high` value that we know are lower and higher, respectively, than the square root, and then doing math to get them closer to the correct value.

When `x` is between 0 and 1, the square root of `x` is greater than `x` itself. Therefore we can't just set `high` to `x`, because it needs to start out higher than the desired answer. But in these cases we also know that the square root of `x` is less than 1, so 1 will work as an initial `high` value. (Similarly, when `x` is greater than 1, the square root of `x` will also be greater than 1, but it will be less than `x`.)

Comment: yaa square root of 0.9 is 0.94243(something). So, if that happens will max pass 1.0 instead of 1 i.e. max(1.0,1) ? can you please explain little bit more @KarlKnechtel

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand the question.